# Xcode - Special characters in JSON

Tags: ios, json, xcode, character-encoding, special-characters

Im loading a database from a website through JSON. When I download the database I use UTF8 to make all characters appear correctly and when I NSLOG them it all appears as it should. But when I analyze the data using JSON and afterwards try to filter out just a few of the words, the words with special characters become like this: "H\U00f6ghastighetst\U00e5g" where it should say: "Höghastighetståg".

I have tried to find a way to make the code convert the text back to UTF8 after filtering but somehow I can't make it happen. Would be really helpful for some answers.

```
NSError *error;
 NSString *url1 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.pumba.se/example.json"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

NSLog(@"Before converting to NSData: %@", url1);

NSData *allCoursesData = [url1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSMutableDictionary *JSONdictionary = [NSJSONSerialization
                                       JSONObjectWithData:allCoursesData
                                       options:kNilOptions
                                       error:&error];
if( error )
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
else {
    NSMutableArray *allNames = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray* entries = [JSONdictionary valueForKeyPath:@"hits.hits"];

    for (NSDictionary *hit in entries) {
        NSArray *versions = hit[@"versions"];
        for (NSDictionary *version in versions) {
            NSDictionary *properties = version[@"properties"];
            NSString *status = [properties[@"Status"] firstObject];
            NSString *name = [properties[@"Name"] firstObject];
            if ([status isEqualToString:@"usable"]) {
                [allNames addObject:name];
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"All names: %@", allNames);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
+ (NSString *)utf8StringEncoding:(NSString *)message
{
    NSString *uniText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[message UTF8String]];
    NSData *msgData = [uniText dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
    message = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:msgData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return message;
}
```

or

```
+ (NSString *)asciiStringEncoding:(NSString *)message
{
    const char *jsonString = [message UTF8String];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithBytes:jsonString length:strlen(jsonString)];
    message = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
    return message;
}
```

and this code can help you

```
+ (NSDictionary *)jsonStringToObject:(NSString *)jsonString
{
    NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *jsonResponse;
    if (data)
        jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    return jsonResponse;
}

+ (NSString *)objectToJsonString:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    if (jsonData.length > 0 && !error)
    {
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        return jsonString;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jose920405 but I don't think I have the skills to know how to implement that in to my current code I'm afraid :/

Comment: Instead of   "H\U00f6ghastighetst\U00e5g" I'm now receiving "H\\366ghastighetst\\345g".